# Section Names In Table Views

Tags: swift, tableview, textfield, sections

How can I take a text of textfield, and make it as name of a section in a tableview? I want to do this in Swift and Xcode 6. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a UITextField in every cell on the table? Or is there a `self.textField` somewhere that sets a header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `titleForHeaderInSection`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String!{
        if (section == 0){
            return textfield.text
        }
        if (section == 1){
            return textfield2.text
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 3.0**
come from @Christian 's answer.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        return ""
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```